# Symplectic Forms on Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, bilinear-form, symplectic-linear-algebra

If $G$ is finite group such that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian (i.e., $G$ is nilpotent of class at most 2) then the commutator function
$$\varphi\colon G/Z(G)\times G/Z(G)\to G^\prime$$
given by $\varphi(g,h)=g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ satisfies the identities (in additive notation):

1. $\varphi(x,x)=0$,
2. $\varphi(x,y)=-\varphi(y,x)$,
3. $\varphi(x+y,z)=\varphi(x,z)+\varphi(y,z)$,
4. $\varphi(x,y+z)=\varphi(x,y)+\varphi(x,z)$,
5. If $\varphi(x,y)=0$ for all $y$ then $x=0$,
6. If $\varphi(x,y)=0$ for all $x$ then $y=0$.

If $G^\prime$ is cyclic of order $p$ then $G/Z(G)$ is an $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space and $\varphi$ is a symplectic bilinear form on $G/Z(G)$.

With this in mind, fix an abelian group $A$ and define a **symplectic $A$-space** to be a finite abelian group $B$ together with a function $\varphi\colon B\times B\to A$ satisfying the above conditions (yes, I realize that conditions 2 and 6 are redundant).

> Is there a classification of symplectic $A$-spaces up to isomorphism?

---

If $A$ is trivial then $B$ is trivial.

If $A$ is cyclic of order $p$ then symplectic $A$-spaces are the same as symplectic $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector spaces. In particular, every symplectic $A$-space has order $p^{2n}$, and there is exactly one symplectic $A$-space of every such order.

In general, if $A$ is cyclic of order $n$ then [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/58828) shows that $B\cong C\times\widehat{C}$ for some finite abelian group $C$ of exponent dividing $n$. This gives a nice classification of symplectic $A$-spaces in the cyclic case.

I'm interested about what happens when $A$ is not assumed to be cyclic.

Comment: I know this is not what you asked, but I want to remark that $G$ is not determined up to isomorphism by $A, \varphi$. Consider the dihedral group and quaternion group. In the case $p=2$ the missing piece of data is a "quadratic refinement" of $\varphi$, that is a function $q$ such that $q(0)=0$ and $\varphi(x,y)=q(x+y)-q(x)-q(y)$. All symplectic forms of given dimension are isomorphic but there are two inequivalent refinements. I don't know how the story goes at the level of generality you are asking, but I am led to believe that symplectic space is not entirely the "right" datum to look at.